# Rails+Capistrano: Sidekiq doesn't always start when new code is deployed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, capistrano, sidekiq

I am sometimes having issues with Sidekiq when deploying new code with using Capistrano.

This is my setup (`deploy/production.rb`):

```
set :rails_env, "production"
set :stage, :production

set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
require "whenever/capistrano"

set :user, 'deployer'
set :use_sudo, false

before "deploy", "deploy:setup"
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

server "IP", :web, :app, :db, primary: true
set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/apps/myapp-production/"

set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
set :keep_releases, 3

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp-production #{command}"
    end
  end
  task :setup_config, roles: [:app] do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx_production.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init_production.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp-production"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: [:app] do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"
  after "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:restart"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: [:web] do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end

  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      begin
        from = source.next_revision(current_revision) # <-- Fail here at first-time deploy because of current/REVISION absence
      rescue
        err_no = true
      end
      if err_no || capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{asset_env} assets:precompile}
      else
        logger.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end
  end

  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

What sometimes happens is that I deploy some code and one time Sidekiq is running and the other time it doesn't. I'd say the ratio is that 1/5 cases Sidekiq is not running (is not restarted) after deploying new code.

How to ensure that Sidekiq will always be running (properly restarted) after every deployment?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

`deploy.rb`:

```
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"
require "rvm/capistrano"
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'delayed/recipes' # added for running deplayed jobs
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'

set :application, 'myapp'
set :bundle_flags, "--quiet --no-cache"

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :repository, 'git@bitbucket.org:username/myapp.git'
set :branch, "master"

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

set :pty, true
```

**EDIT2:**
Also, I am not sure if this is related, but sometimes when I change something in the `/config` folder, I need to log in to the (Ubuntu) server, kill the unicorn process and manually start the server to see the change.

Comment: i see no sidekiq deployment code in you capistrano config. How you deploy your sidekiq?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this part. I added the `deploy.rb` part.

Comment: @user984621 Do you get any errors in sidekiq log?

Comment: @Sebin No errors, it's just not running; if I send a request that use Sidekiq, then this request is stored in Redis and once Sidekiq is running, this request is picked up from Redis and processed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with Capistrano 3, set pty to false should resolve the problem.

> There is a known bug that prevents sidekiq from starting when pty is true on Capistrano 3.
>
> set :pty,  false

https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq#known-issues-with-capistrano-3

Related issue:
https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq/issues/23